# Camel REST - Path based routing

Tags: rest, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have to develop a Camel REST route with path-based routing.
The scenario is as follows: we have a business partner which provided a REST web service for displaying documents. The REST web service is deployed on 3  different servers, depending on the geographic location.
So we basically have 3 server like these:

```
http://north.acme.com/flowdocv2/rest/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
http://center.acme.com/flowdocv2/rest/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
http://south.acme.com/flowdocv2/rest/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
```

My aim is to develop a *single* Camel route to map these server, accepting the name of the server in the path. Something like this:

```
http://my.camel.com/center/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
http://my.camel.com/north/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
http://my.camel.com/south/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
```

My (simplified and not working) blueprint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0    
    https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd  
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="my.config.file"/>

<reference id="sharedNettyHttpServer" interface="org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettySharedHttpServer"/>

<camelContext id="my_context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <restConfiguration component="netty4-http">
        <endpointProperty key="nettySharedHttpServer" value="#sharedNettyHttpServer"/>
    </restConfiguration>
    <rest path="/center/repository">
        <get uri="/attachment/{attachmentId}/findById">
            <route streamCache="true" trace="true">
                <to uri="http://center.acme.com/flowdocv2/rest?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
            </route>
        </get>            
    </rest>
    <rest path="/north/repository">
        <get uri="/attachment/{attachmentId}/findById">
            <route streamCache="true" trace="true">
                <to uri="http://north.acme.com/flowdocv2/rest?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
            </route>
        </get>            
    </rest>
</camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to remove /center, /north or /south from the path, so the header is forwared to the destination service, which doesn't know how to deal with it.
Invoking:

```
http://my.camel.com/center/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
```

results in the following URL being invoked on the destination server:

```
http://center.acme.com/flowdocv2/rest/center/repository/attachment/{id}/findById
```

How to get rid of *center*? I don't want to deploy 3 camel routes on different ports.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it is actually a bit easier. As long as you do not hang onto netty and you are using Camel 2.11+ you can use [camel-urlrewrite](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-urlrewrite/src/main/docs/urlrewrite.adoc)

Basically, you define a single rewrite rule in a configuration and add this to your route bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
    <urlrewrite>
        <rule>
            <name>Generic Proxy</name>
            <note>
                This rule completely rewrites the url to call.
                Basically, in Camel's "to", you could write whatever you want
            </note>
            <from>^/(.*?)/(.*)</from>
            <to>http://$1.acme.com/flowdocv2/rest/$2</to>
        </rule>
    </urlrewrite>
```

Now, you can utilize a rather simple route:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0    
    https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd  
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="myRewrite" class="org.apache.camel.component.urlrewrite.HttpUrlRewrite">
        <property name="configFile" value="class/path/to/proxyrewrite.xml" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="my_context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="proxyRoute">
            <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:9090/proxy" />
            <to uri="jetty:http://somewhere/myapp2?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false&amp;urlRewrite=#myRewrite" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

However, netty is not supported, so I chose the next best thing.

When you call `http://localhost:9090/proxy/north/foo`, the rewrite will actually change the url to call to `http://north.acme.com/flowdoc2/rest/foo`.

There are a few caveats with this. First, you have to use one of the supported components for UrlRewrite. Second, it seems that you have to have the rewrite config file in you *classpath* - so no blueprint-only route. Third: I did not test it, but I think you get the gist. I make this a community wiki answer, so that others, more capable than me, can expand on this answer.

Comment: I found a solution similar to yours, although not elegant, manipulating the headers in order to remove from CamelHttpUri and CamelHttpPath the non-relevant part.